# Align Listview with other elements of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am creating an app, in which there's a functionality to select time (in hour and minutes). For which, I have created two listviews, one for selecting hour and other for selecting minute. Both listviews should have seven items visible. and then there are two textviews which should be aligned with 4th item's bottom. You can see the screenshot to understand it better.

[image: screenshot]

The UI should look like the image. But, the problem is, the alignment changes with different screen resolutions. I tried to set different margins and sizes for different dpis (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi). But, still for some devices (e.g., S4) the views don't align and the listview shows top part of 8th item. I tested the app on emulators with diff. resolutions and it's working fine there.

The code in xml layout file :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:visibility="visible">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/hourList"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/timerListViewWidth"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="63dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hrs"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottomPaddingListPostFix" <!-- diff. for diff. dpis-->
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hourList"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/minList"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/timerListViewWidth"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="63dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="min"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottomPaddingListPostFix"  <!-- diff. for diff. dpis-->
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minList"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and the code for listview row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:duplicateParentState="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="24"
    android:textColor="@drawable/row_selector"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/timerListViewItemTextSize" />  <!-- diff. for diff. dpis-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to manage this dynamically for all diff. screen sizes and resolutions? If yes, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Add two more custom listview , one for hrs and one for min
2) Disable Scrolling for those two listview using this code

In your CustomListView:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
   if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
      return true;
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Then ListView will react to clicks, but will not change scroll position.

3) And Use same logic to display hrs and min as you used for white color

Comment: Guys mark the correct answer. So that, it will be helpful for others to refer and implement directly.

Comment: Thanks Darshil. I created the listviews for hrs and mins, with row height same as the listview with digits. But, there was no need to disable scrolling, as I created listviews with only 4 items so that last item will be the title, 'hrs' or 'mins'.

Sorry for the delay in marking your answer as correct.